# MFC: Determine if command is enabled or disabled?

Tags: mfc

I have a timer setup where I want to issue a `WM_COMMAND` at those timer intervals.   The command is already enabled/disabled via the `ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI`.

I'd like to leverage what already exists and only call the `WM_COMMAND` if the command is enabled.  Is there a way to leverage what exists, determine if command is enabled, without have to do the same checks/logic that `ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI` does?

TIA!!

Answer (score 2):

There is an issue with synchronizing (not in the multithreading meaning, there is no multithreading here) updates and command handlers scheduled by the framework: it won't call the update handler immediately before calling the command handler. It would be best to force call the update handler before, and if the UI item has been disabled then not call the command handler. This would allow the developer to have the whole UI-update logic (concerning one specific command) in one place and not have to mess with it anywhere else. The problem is that the update handler is called during idle-time processing, ie it is the last operation to be executed before the application becomes really idle. This is not generally considered a great issue though, as the update handler will finally run in the next few milliseconds or seconds, and the item(s) will be updated. The problem basically concerns the case where the user issues a command, eg presses a shortcut key combination, while the application is executing a previously called operation that could have caused the UI item to be disabled - the framework will call the (new) command handler, and not perform the update, as because of having pending commands in the queue, the system isn't considered to be in "idle-time". So if the operation is critical enough, you will have to run the update code before, just to be sure. An oversight imo unfortunately, in an otherwise excellent and very well conceived mechanism, not found in any other language or framework.

Therefore, due to the issue described above and also due to the fact that the timer calls aren't affected by the UI status anyway, there is no way to easily *leverage what already exists*, at least the way you may mean it. You will rather have to do it yourself, which isn't hard at all: define a boolean function, containing the enable/disable logic, ideally at the same level of instantiation (class member, global etc) as the UI item and the command handler; then you just have to call the function both in `pCmdUI->Enable()` and in the command handler, before executing the actual data processing commands.

Comment: I like putting that kind of check at the top of the OnWhateverCommand() method to handle wherever it might be actively called outside the normal built-in "command" mechanism, including this situation.